# Combine Two matrices A and B,selecting elements first from A and second from B, in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am working on my project with matlab and I need to combine two matrices like this:

A and B are 16*50 matrices

My new matrix C should be as this:

```
C =

A(1,1)  A(1,2) ... A(1,50) 

B(1,1)  B(1,2) ... B(1,50)

A(2,1)  A(2,2) ... A(2,50)

B(2,1)  B(2,2) ... B(2,50)

 .       .            .

 .       .            .

 .       .            .

A(16,1) A(16,2) ... A(16,50)

B(16,2) B(16,2) ... B(16,50)
```

How can I do this please help.Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should definitely read @woodchips' answer first: it's important to learn how MATLAB stores arrays in memory.

In any case, I would go for:

```
C = zeros(2,16,50);
C(1,:) = A(:);
C(2,:) = B(:);
C = reshape(C, 32, 50);
```

or

```
C = zeros(32,50);
C(1:2:end,:) = A;
C(2:2:end,:) = B;
```

Since these approaches avoid re-ordering the elements.

Comment: thank u for ur help.
I have done like this:

C=[];

for t=1:50
    
    for h=1:2:32
        
        C(h,t)=A(((h+1)/2),t);

    end

end

for k=1:50
    
    for l= 2:2:32
        
        C(l,k)=B((l/2),l);

    end

end

Comment: I have tried all the answers they all work!The result is same as mine.Thank you.Your answers are shorter way.

Comment: I like the second suggestion here, I think it's a lot more obvious what you're trying to do than with any of the other suggestions. It's what I would do.

Comment: Don't do it in a loop. Please!

Comment: @ÇiğdemÖzer: It is not true that their solutions are simply a "shorter way". Your solution has a bug and won't work. Furthermore Nzbuu's solution is incredibly superior to yours in terms of speed, efficiency and elegance. Please accept his solution to guide other users with the same problem.

Comment: For what it's worth, I think that the first one will be fastest and easiest to generalise, but the second one is clearest.

Answer (score 5):

Learn to visualize where the array elements are in memory, and how tools like reshape, permute, etc., operate on those elements.

First, can you simply combine the two matrices one on top of each other? [A;B] will suffice of course.

What would happen if you then used reshape on the result? So something like this...

```
reshape([A;B],[16,2,50])
```

Next, what happens if you apply permute?

```
permute(reshape([A;B],[16,2,50]),[2 1 3])
```

Are we getting close? What if you did a reshape on THAT result? (Yes, you might want to do all of this in several steps to make it readable. Readable code is terribly important when you need to debug it next month or next year. As important are comment lines that tell what a block of code does.)

```
% interleave the rows of matrices A and B to create C
C = reshape([A;B],[16,2,50])
C = permute(C,[2 1 3]);
C = reshape(C,[32,50]);
```

The point is, learn to use the tools in matlab to move your elements around in memory with your target in mind. Before you are done, don't forget those comments. Easily read code is easily debugged code. If the single line of comment I suggested is inadequate for you, then add more lines. Comments are virtually free! They cost you nothing more than a few seconds to write, and no time to execute, but they improve your code immeasurably.

Comment: thank u for ur help.
I have done like this:

C=[];

for t=1:50
    
    for h=1:2:32
        
        C(h,t)=A(((h+1)/2),t);

    end

end

for k=1:50
    
    for l= 2:2:32
        
        C(l,k)=B((l/2),l);

    end

end

Comment: ARGH!!!! While this may indeed do it, it also means that you did not learn anything from what I said. Read my response again. See that when you make loops and nested loops in matlab, you are often writing inefficient, unnecessary code. Ok, on this problem it might not make a lot of difference, but on your next problem it will. The point is to learn how elements are stored in matlab, and how to move them around efficiently.

Comment: No,I have understood your answer. The answer that I wrote was inefficient I know, that is why I asked you :)